# Why VS code is not detecting Laravel blade code?

Tags: php, laravel-5, visual-studio-code

[image]

My laravel code is not detected by VS code and it does not colour highligt the code. Laravel snippets are also not working. Is there any wat to resolve this?

Comment: Do you have an extension installed that highlights blade files?

Answer (score 3):

### The .blade.php Is for the Laravel Framework. It's Not a Programming Language

**Here are some Good Vscode Extensions :**

[#1] [Laravel Blade Snippets - 1+ million Downloads](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=onecentlin.laravel-blade)

[#2] [Laravel Snippets - 600k Downloads](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=onecentlin.laravel5-snippets)

**Here are some good extension Packs !**

[Should get You started with Laravel](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=onecentlin.laravel-extension-pack)